# Trying to divide a number by an array's elements, to check if it's prime (kinda)

Tags: c#

My goal is for the user to enter a number, the program to divide it with each element from an array and then say if the number is prime or not.
This is the best I have come so far:

```
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int i = 0;
int[] div = {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
int result;


do
{
    result = number / div[i];
    i++;
} while ((result % 1) == 0);

if ((result % 1) != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number seems to be prime for now");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I know there's a problem but I can't figure it out. Also I might change the code, based on my progress and research.

Comment: What do you think that `result % 1` does?  Then look at the data type of `result` and see if that changes your answer?

Comment: Please don't ask a question if you are still researching it. Wait until you're done with that part of the process. Otherwise, someone could be in the middle of writing an answer, and you delete your question because you found the answer during your research. That's not fair to the answerer.

Comment: Like others, I can't quite follow what you are doing.  As @BenVoigt points out `result % 1` isn't really what you are looking for.  If you want to check that an integer is evenly divisible by another integer, you want to check that `number % divisor` is zero or not (interestingly you can also check if `number / divisor * divisor` is equal to `number` (let that sink in a bit)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get stuck on a programming problem, break it into parts.

First, write a function that can tell you if a number is divisible by another number.

```
bool IsDivisibleBy(int dividend, int divisor)
{
    return (dividend % divisor) == 0;
}
```

Now write a function that will accept a list of divisors and do the same thing.

```
bool IsDivisibleByAny(int dividend, int[] divisors)
{
    foreach (var divisor in divisors)
    {
        bool isDivisible = IsDivisibleBy(dividend, divisor);
        if (isDivisible) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or one line with Linq (if you have gotten that far yet):

```
bool IsDivisibleByAny(int dividend, IEnumerable<int> divisors) =>
    divisors.Any( divisor => IsDivisibleBy(dividend, divisor) );
```

Now your main program is very easy to write:

```
var divisors = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
bool isDivisible = IsDivisibleByAny(number, divisors);
if (!isDivisible)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number seems to be prime for now");
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the pedagogic value of the intent. My own answer is only a pedagogic post that merely try to get the op to think about the problem. Maybe you should just then warn there is a hidden error, so that your answer is nor to be mistaken as buggy?

Comment: I deleted my comment to respect your intention

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the answer you expect.

If we discard the first number (1), it seems your array `div` is a (very) partial list of primes. If you already know the prime numbers, you could simply check if the number entered is in that list. If yes it is a prime number.

While it could look like cheating, it is actually a widely used technique (calculating sinus/cosinus in signal processors for instance).

That could be implemented in several ways.

As a Linq query:

```cs
int Candidate; // The variable in which you store the read number.

var Primes = new List<int> { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, [...]}; // Could be obtained by parsing an external file.

var IsPrime = Primes.Any(p => p == Candidate);
```

Or for better computational efficiency, in a `HashSet` (a not so often used data structure. It could be replaced by the widely used `Dictionary`):

```cs
int Candidate; // The variable in which you store the read number.

var Primes = new HashSet<int> { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, [...]}; // Could be obtained by parsing an external file.

var IsPrime = Primes.Contains(Candidate);
```

If you need a file with prime numbers, see https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/millions/

You'll notice the interesting comment on the page:

> In this directory I have the first fifty million primes in blocks of
> one million.  Usually it is faster to run a program on your own
> computer than to download them, but by popular demand, here they are!

I hope it will motivate you to find how he does!

This leads to another path: actually calculate if a number is prime, but then your `div` array should not contains all these values (because you want to calculate then, right?).

This is another subject altogether, and I won't extend on this. For the record, the first known way to calculate the prime numbers was the Erastothenes' sieve.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Notice than checking if a number is prime and calculating primes is a different problem (even if the first can be deduced by solving the second).

A last comment:

The two general methods I outlined: referring to an already computed list, and calculating, are good examples of tradeoffs.

- the first one generally requires a large amount of memory, for very little computation power.
- the second one might require a smaller amount of memory, but trading it for a large computation power.

In the case of prime number, neither tradeoff seems evidently better than the other, but in the the sinus/cosinus case I mentioned previously, using already computed values is tremendously advantageous, because of the cyclic nature of these functions. You only need a finite amount of memory space to store all the needed values. (assuming you don't need an infinite precision of course).

Comment: Wouldn't using a `HashSet<int>` make more sense than a `Dictionary<int, bool>`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'll correct.

Comment: I suggest defining "seems to be prime" as "is relatively prime to all numbers in the list", a property which can be tested for numbers much larger than the length of the list

Comment: Yes, in that case, the `div` list, even as small as it is, becomes interesting for computation.